# Error: unable to access jarfile localhost

Tags: java

I have to write two programs: server and client - running server on some port, running client also on that port. I run everything on my computer and as argument of client program I have localhost as machine address, but for some reason it is treated like *jarfile*. I have:

```
String hostname = args[0];
int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
...
Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
...
```

Calling it with:

```
java -jar client.jar localhost 1234
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error: unable to access jarfile localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I didn't seal whole JAR, just some packages, so my program didn't recognize localhost as an address of machine.